# setting up proxy in webview programmatically

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am running emulator behind proxy. I have successfully setup proxy in emulator and browser is running fine with internet connectivity. But the webview component in the application I am developing is not getting connected with Internet behind proxy.
        Does anyone knows how to either set proxy in webview or can copy settings from emulator browser onto webview component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the same problem. It was solved.

[android WebView internet access problem, because of proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673159/android-webview-internet-access-problem-because-of-proxy)

Hope it help.