# android WebView internet access problem, because of proxy?

Tags: android

Here is my problem:

Emulator(Android 2.2) is able to access internet through browser.
(I am behind a proxy so i set the proxy first)

but when i create a webview app, seems like it can not access the internet by webview.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

is set up. So I am afraid it's because of the proxy.

Any clue ? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding In OnCreate()

```
WebView.enablePlatformNotifications();
```

And adding the following permissions to the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

This should enable your webview to access the proxy info it needs.  You may need to restart your emulator (hopefully not).

Comment: yes! it works ,and also needs to add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>, thank you very much

Comment: yes! yes! yes! it works. How do you find out such things, really? My app was giving URL not found errorCode = -2 with webview for a particular service provider. Your change fixed it!! Thanks!!

Comment: This method is deprecated.
Obsolete - platform notifications are always enabled. 

Enables platform notifications of data state and proxy changes.

Answer (score 1):

For me, my apps cannot access webViews unless I specify a DNS server for my Android simulators.  This is how I solve the issue in eclipse:

- Eclipse > Preferences > Android > Launch:
- Default emulator options:
- dns-server 8.8.8.8

You must also add "-dns-server 8.8.8.8" for any Android Run Configurations already created.

- Run > Run Configurations > Select Android Project > Target Tab >
  Additional Emulator Command Line Options:
- Add "-dns-server 8.8.8.8"
  here.

Not sure if this will help with your issue, but hopefully it does.

Comment: I figured it out according to Justin's solution, but thanks anyway.