# trigger apps accesing REST servive on android emulator using proxy

Tags: android-emulator, trigger.io

I've succesfully built and loaded part 3 of the [trigger.io weather app tutorial](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/tutorials/weather/index.html), and it runs fine and downloads the weather information when the emulator is not configured to use a proxy.

But when I configure the emulator to use a proxy the ajax call fails, tracing the following to the command prompt:

```
[   INFO] D/Forge   (  362): Native call "internal.hideLaunchImage" with task.params: {}
[   INFO] I/Forge   (  362): No reload update available.
[   INFO] D/Forge   (  362): Returning: {"content":{"type":"UNEXPECTED_FAILURE","message":"Forge Java error: NullPointerException: null"},"status":"error","callid":"D4506031-17C9-4074-8689-5F3E7933649D"}
[   INFO] D/Forge   (  362): Native call "logging.log" with task.params: {"message":"   [FORGE] 'ERROR! [getWeatherInfo] undefined'","level":20}
```

From the answer to the question [android WebView internet access problem, because of proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673159/android-webview-internet-access-problem-because-of-proxy) it seems I need to grant permission to the app to use the proxy. Can anyone tell me if and how I can do this in trigger.io?

Thanks

Comment: @KrisKrause. Yep, I got a prompt (on Saturday!) response from Amir Nathoo to a  support question I sent to trigger.io - but unfortunately using a proxy in Android WebView is not currently supported. They are however looking into it, it would probably be worth contacting about it - the more requests they get, the higher priority they are likely to give it.

Comment: I'll report back here when support for this is available.