# webView with proxy setting

Tags: android, webview, 3g

I just know that :WebView.enablePlatformNotifications();  it's obsoleted now. I add this code in my Activity

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("X.X.X.X", portNumber); //proxy that i need 

    httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRouteParams.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
```

and I add this code:

```
WebView testWebView = new WebView(this);
// WebView.enablePlatformNotifications();// it's obsoleted!
testWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

The result is : my device cannot open google.com through 3g.

How can I make testWebView known the proxy I have stetted?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488338/webview-android-proxy

Answer (score -1):

You should follow this links it may be helpful to you.

- https://gist.github.com/2297083
- [WebView android proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488338/webview-android-proxy)
- [android WebView internet access problem, because of proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673159/android-webview-internet-access-problem-because-of-proxy)

Comment: I saw them before. As you see, the second website link is useless.  thanks also the same. I am still confuse that why I can search the web by 3g. But if i change to wifi,it's ok!

Comment: finally, the problem was solved . The reason is that the sim card has some design defect . So ... Thank